# How can Big-O be proved using derivatives?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Say we have: $$f(n) \in O(g(n))$$
By definition we need to show that:
$$0 \le f(n) \le c\cdot g(n) $$
for some $c>0$ and for all $n>n_0$.

This is usually not difficult when rational and polynomial functions are involved, but if functions have logarithms and square roots, I get confused and not sure how to proceed. I know there has to be a calculus proof, but I'm unaware of it.

Would it be enough to show that:
$$c\cdot g(n) - f(n) \ge 0 $$

And to do that we need to find the minimum point by deriving it (which we can use as n0), and showing that the slope is always positive?

Comment: Could you add a concrete example that you have difficulty with? That would make it much easier to give an instructive answer.

Comment: A function may have a positive slope on $I=[x_0,+\infty)$ without being positive at any point in $I$.

Answer (score 2):

Your general idea is  reasonable, but some details need work. Looking for a minimum of $cg-f$ will likely be a waste of time. The basic fact to use is:

> If $h(x_0)>0$ and $h'(x)>0$  for all $x>x_0$, then $h(x)>0$ for all $x>x_0$.

A formal proof of the above involves the mean value theorem: $h(x)-h(x_0)=h'(\xi)(x-x_0)>0$.

As an example, let's show that $\ln x=O(x^\epsilon)$ for any (fixed) $\epsilon>0$. Introduce $$h(x)=Cx^\epsilon-\ln x$$ and calculate $$h'(x)=C\epsilon x^{\epsilon-1}-x^{-1} = x^{-1}(C\epsilon x^\epsilon -1)$$
Turns out, it's not even necessary to take large $x_0$: we can pick $x_0=1$ for simplicity. Choosing $C=1/\epsilon$ makes sure that $h'(x)=x^{-1}(x^\epsilon-1)>0$ for all $x>1$. And since $h(1)=C>0$, we are done.